# Passing C# 3D array to C++ library as 1D byte array

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, dll, c#-3.0

I have a C# application where i created a 3D Int16(short) array. Want to pass this 3D array to a c++ library to set this data to an object in a form of 1D byte array. So the scenarios is either to convert it before passing the data to the library or converting it in the library itself.

- I know how to convert the 3D Int16 array to 1D byte array in C# but I don't know how to convert it using C++?
- Which one will be faster C++ or C#, regarding that I use `ConvertAll` in C#?
- Will the memory be doubled or I can just set the data of the object in the C++ library  to point to the same volume I have in C#?

Comment: by C++ do you mean managed C++ ?

Comment: Assuming a M X N X R matrix, are you talking about converting it to a one-dimensional array of size M*N*R and passing it to the C++ function? Why can't you just pass a WORD*** to the c++ function? Is this CLI C++ or standard C++?

Comment: The object in the server[c++] is taking its data in byte[] form

Answer (score 2):

> I know how to convert the 3D Int16 array to 1D byte array in C# but I
>   don't know how to convert it using C++?

This depends on how you want the rows, columns, and depth arranged in the one-dimensional array. I don't see any reason to convert it, as you can just randomly access the elements in the way that you want them. There is no reason to take on the cost of such an operation when you don't have to. If you aren't storing this in a file or sending it across the network I can't understand why you would want to serialize it.

Why can't you do something like:

```
__declspec( dllexport ) void cppMatrixCode(__int16*** matrix_3d, int width, int height, int depth)
{
   //manipulate the matrix with matrix_3d[the row you want][col you want][depth you want]

   //or to serialize:
   for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
     for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
       for(int k = 0; k < depth; k++)
       {
         _int16 value = matrix_3d[i][j][k];
         //now add value to another array or whatever you want.
       }
}

in C#
[DllImport("YourDLLGoesHere")]
static extern void cppMatrixCode(short[,,] matrix_3d, int width, int height, int depth);

short[,,] matrix = new short[width, height, depth];
//add your values to matrix
cppMatrixCode(matrix, width, height, depth);
```

This should only copy 128 bytes on a 32 bit system, or 160 bytes on a 64 bit system.

> Which one will be faster C++ or C#, regarding that I use ConvertAll in
>   C#?

This depends on what in particular you are doing, but well written C++ code is usually faster than CLI code.

> Will the memory be doubled or I can just set the data of the object in
>   the C++ library to point to the same volume I have in C#?

You should be able to pass the C# byte[] to the c++ function by reference and without copying any data. Once again though, we need more details on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: In the client application i have a 3D array which represents the volume data. the server takes the data on whatever form and convert it to a 1D byte array to pass it to a 3D volume object [muvolumeobj.Data=1D byte array] ,as server is written in c++ i have tow ways ,either to convert the 3D array to 1D byte[] then pass it to the server , or just pass the 3D array to the server and it will handle it.NOTE: that in the clinet i need the data to be 3D to handle some other modules like MPR